# Is there any way to track firestore read and writes?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am having a hard time understanding how read and writes are calculated in firestore. According to their docs every change to a document is one write but yesterday the firebase console showed me I had done 21k writes in a matter of 1.5 hours which is just ridiculous given I am the only user of my application. Is there any firebase log or something which will help me see all 21k writes which I supposedly made?

Answer (score 1):

you can check your general reads and writes in the GCP console but there is no native integration to know where these are coming from - you could use analytics but that would be problematic to introduce app-wide.

Instead, you should look at your app's behavior and assess if any function is caught in a potential loop, loading multiple writes based on minor changes within your app, or making batch writes in a CRON pubsub cloud function or a cloud function onUpdate that is self-triggering.

Answer (score 0):

There are no native integrations, but i found a hacky ay to at least log the collections or docs being accesed.
You have to modify the prototype of the collection or doc function this
way:

```
export const fs = admin.firestore()
const docFunc = fs.doc

fs.doc = (path: string) => {
    console.log('Accessing doc', path)
    return docFunc.call(fs, path)
}
```

That way if you later do

```
import { fs } from './db'
fs.collection('your-collection').doc('your-doc')
```

You will get a log saying
Accessing doc `your-collection/your-doc`